# Weird symbol on gnome-terminal profile preferences Window

Tags: gnome-terminal

Strange symbol appears on the `gnome-terminal`'s profile preferences window.

[image]

Is this a bug? Is that possible to get the symbol out?

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Are you using ATI graphics with the proprietary driver by any chance? I've heard that it can cause artifacts like this.

Comment: no, i didn't install any graphics drivers.